# servicestack GlobalRequestFilters request Dto coming null

Tags: c#, .net, api, servicestack

I have a **ServiceStack**  `GlobalRequestFilters` filter in the `apphost` file that catch the authenticate request, the filter is working fine but the problem is in the dto in `req` , `res` and `requestDto` is null ??!

```
this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) => {
     if (req.OperationName.ToLower()== "authenticate")
     {
         var authData =req.GetDto();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `requestDto` is passed in the filter itself, i.e:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) => {
    var authDto = requestDto as Authenticate;
    if (authDto != null)
    {
        //...
    }
});
```

An alternative approach to the above is to use a Typed Request Filter, e.g:

```
RegisterTypedRequestFilter<Authenticate>((req, res, authDto) => {
    //...
});
```

Comment: its not fired up filter  when i hit login so i cant detect the request or the dto

Comment: @moathnaji I don't understand what you're saying? The Global Request Filter gets called for each Service Request, if the client is making an `Authenticate` request it will get called.

Comment: still get it null requestDto >> attributes come's null

Comment: @moathnaji it's impossible to get a `null` requestDto, if it's not populated that's a different issue and you'll need to make sure the Service is called correctly.

Comment: @moathnaji that just means the request which executed the filter was not an `Authenticate` Request DTO, you should be able to tell what Type the Request DTO is from the debugger or you can get the name with `requestDto.GetType().Name`.